# How to Use html <ruby> tags in Swift 4 for Japanese Characters

Tags: html, swift, xcode, cjk

I need to use html  tags for Japanese characters in Swift.

I've been using the following string extension below:

```
extension String{
func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString{
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
    do{
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    }catch{
        return NSAttributedString()
    }
}
```

And then testing it out with a textView as follows:

```
textView.attributedText = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>これは<ruby>日<rt>に</rt>本<rt>ほん</rt>語<rt>ご</rt></ruby>です。</body></html>".convertHtml()
```

This is how it should actually look:

```html
これは<ruby>日<rt>に</rt>本<rt>ほん</rt>語<rt>ご</rt></ruby>です。
```

But it ends up looking like this. It doesn't line up properly, and there is a strange line break after every single use of the ruby tag.

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong here, and a way to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: This `let japStr = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><ruby>これは日に本ほん語ごです。</ruby></body></html>"` works, I'm not an expert in HTML, but did you really need all theses subtags?

Comment: Yes, they are necessary for the small text to appear above the Japanese characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *whole line* of Japanese text should be enclosed in `<ruby>` tags. This is because the `<ruby>` element sets up its own inline context, yet its sub-elements such as `<rb>`, `<rt>`, `<rp>`, and `<rtc>` also set up their own contexts like 'block' that only really make sense when the whole line is enclosed in a `<ruby>` element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- In case you'd like to try opening this page in desktop Safari! -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ruby>
            <rb>これ</rb><rt></rt>
            <rb>は</rb><rt></rt>
            <rb>日</rb><rt>に</rt>
            <rb>本</rb><rt>ほん</rt>
            <rb>語</rb><rt>ご</rt>
            <rb>です</rb><rt></rt>
            <rb>。</rb><rt></rt>
        </ruby>
        <span>But this <em>isn't</em> Japanese.</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

I find it's best to be explicit about **every** `<ruby>` sub-element, and to also pair every `<rb>` (ruby base text) with a corresponding `<rt>` (ruby transcription). Sure, it looks more redundant and less clean, but it's a lot more semantic and you can be sure it's going to look the same in all browsers.

### Edit showing that HTML is valid

Below, I provide a screenshot of it working. Here's how I invoked it:

```
let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())

webView.loadHTMLString(
    "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><!-- In case you'd like to try opening this page in desktop Safari! --><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"></head><body><ruby><rb>これ</rb><rt></rt><rb>は</rb><rt></rt><rb>日</rb><rt>に</rt><rb>本</rb><rt>ほん</rt><rb>語</rb><rt>ご</rt><rb>です</rb><rt></rt><rb>。</rb><rt></rt></ruby><span>But this <em>isn't</em> Japanese.</span></body></html>",
    baseURL: nil
)
```

[image: Evidence]

If you copy-paste that as-is, do you have any more luck?

### Digression

Seems like `UITextView` interprets all ruby nodes as having a block context. I would therefore argue that either `UITextView`/`NSAttributedString` has not fully implemented the HTML5 specification, or it has bugs, or there is some further configuration to be done. Either way, the easiest way to display this ruby text correctly would be to use a true `WKWebView` (although I understand this has its own tradeoffs like lack of text-to-speech support, and visibly increased time taken to render).

Comment: Thanks for providing this information. Unfortunately it still doesn't solve the issue with the furigana and kanji lining up when called in Swift. I tried your code and it still creates the strange line breaks.

Comment: @AdamS. I've now edited my post with a direct code sample, and proof of it in action. If line breaks still occur despite using my code as-is, then you may need to check that you're not getting any interference from any `WKUserScript`s loaded into the webView, and ensure that you're not including any CSS before/after loading it in.

Comment: @AdamS. Okay, looks like I went off on a tangent, sorry – I guess that even though the HTML is perfectly valid, a `UITextView` or `NSAttributedString` doesn't interpret it the same way that a `WKWebView` does; I would even argue that Apple haven't achieved an accurate interpretation of HTML, as every single text node is given its own line and there's no concept of inline nodes here. I have no experience with `UITextView`, but would you consider using a `WKWebView` for this instead?

Comment: Thank you. This does work. I hadn't considered using a webkit view but it looks like it can do what I need it to. I'm not that familiar with webkit, but would doing it like this allow for offline usage, or does this require a connection to the internet for the user?

Comment: @AdamS. No web connection needed, as you're simply using it to parse some HTML5 and possibly also run some JavaScript (if you want to). You'd only need a web connection if you also wanted to reference external resources or make XmlHttpRequests.

Comment: so, the most important part is to fill the `head` with `<meta charset="UTF-8">`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way which I use.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<style>
fg:before {
 content: attr(t);
 display: block;
    font-size: 50%;
    text-align: start;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

fg {
 display: inline-block;
 text-indent: 0px;
 line-height: normal;
    -webkit-text-emphasis: none;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<fg t="わたし">私</fg>はケンです。<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

See if that might work. It works fine for me in all the browsers I tested.